# Managing ViewBag state from controller, view, partial views & layout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm not understanding how ViewBag state is managed between the controller, view, partial views, _ViewStart and layouts.

In particular, in _ViewStart.cshtml I set

```
@{
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
      ViewContext.ViewBag.Title = "Default Title";
}
```

Yet, in _Layout.cshtml the

```
ViewBag.Title is not defined
```

Should it not be defined?

Comment: As far as I know you should use ViewData and ViewBag to send data from controller to view.

Comment: I think you should use ViewBag.Title instead of ViewContext.ViewBag.Title